# Weird bounty behaviour

Tags: bug, bounty

I just wanted to offer a 50-rep bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218255/linking-to-an-element-with-an-id-not-working-if-linked-outside-the-website). But I couldn't select the 50-rep item, only 100 and more were present and selectable - see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHnqg.png).
I then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles
> with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second,
> 200 on the third, and so on).

But I did not offer a bounty on that question before ! Here a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8rRU.png) of my bounty Offered tab - empty as you can see. Did I do anything wrong, or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because you have already provided an answer to this question.

The [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) also states:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).